# Angular JS - Basic data binding not working

Tags: angularjs

i'm new to angular, so started with very basic example, but this is also not working. so please help me out. below code should write the content of textbox to the page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head ng-app>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" />{{name}}
    </div>
    <script src="/script/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

ng-app should be inside html or body, inside whichever tags you intend to use angular.

Comment: you can include angular.js toward the bottom of page or in the header section, both works

Answer (score 1):

In your code `ng-app` scope is ending with in head tags only. You haven't used `ng-app` at root level. You can use it at `html` or `body` or main `div` tag level. And there is no `ng-controller` in your markup. Of course you can also configure controller through js file also. 
You use below code.

HTML

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.14">    </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="container">
      Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" />{{name}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Comment: Rajeshwar, for this simple example you don't have to create a controller. it  started working by just placing the ng-app in html tag.

Comment: It is required, if you want to pre define your `name` variable. Other wise, i understand its not required.

Comment: does it means, i can use "World" instead of name?

Comment: If you don't use a controller, then text box will not be populated with any value. what ever u enter in the text box will be shown in place of `{{name}}`. But if you want to pre-populate the text box with some value you can define a controller and define variable name and u can assign some value. The the text box will be populated with the value u assigned to `name` variable in the controller.

Comment: thanks Rajeshwar! i implemented the same via controller. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-app` should be in `html` tag, not `head`.

Answer (score 0):

put ng-app in  tag, not in head tag

Answer (score 0):

Remove ng-app directives which is added to head tag and assign it to html